# Evaluate lazily with spring-data

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to have the roles set fetch lazily. Hibernate fetchType.Lazy doesn't work for this cases, where spring data is used. I 've been trying lots of possibilities like Entitygraph but none of them works on this, or I'm using them wrong.
I have the next classes:

A class User:

```
@Entity
@JsonRootName(value = "user")
@Table(name = "web_users", schema = "t_dw_comercial")
public class User {

   @Id
   private int userId;

   private String fullName;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="web_users_roles",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")}
    )
    private List<Role> roles;

}
```

A class Role:

```
    @Entity
    @JsonRootName(value = "roles")
    @Table(name = "web_roles", schema = "t_dw_comercial")
    public class Role {

       @Id
       private int roleId;

       private String roleName;

    }
```

Service:

```
 @Service
    public class UserService implements IUserService{

        @Autowired
        UserRepository repository;

        public User findUserByLdapId(String loginName) {

            return repository.findUserByLdapId(loginName);
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u where u.ldapId= ?1")
public User findUserByLdapId(String loginName);


}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", params = {"user"}, method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<User>  getUser(@RequestParam(value = "user") String ldapId) {

        User user =  userService.findUserByLdapId(ldapId);

        if(user == null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);

    };
}
```

So a json would looks like:

```
{
    "user": {
        "userId": 1,
        "fullName": "Carolina Ponce",
        "roles":[]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're asking for two different things: how to fetch `@OneToMany` association lazily (which should work out of the box) and how to make your JSON look like the above (which has nothing to do with how your `JPA` entity fetching is configured).

If you serialize your entity using Jackson, by default all the fields will get serialized, including those that are fetched lazily. If the persistence context is still open when you begin to serialize the entities, Jackson will simply trigger lazy loading by accessing the property. As a result, regardless of whether you use `FetchType.EAGER` or `FetchType.LAZY`, `roles` *will* be included in the result (I assume it is the case, since you'd be getting a `LazyInitializationException` if the context was closed).

The solution is, simply, to tell Jackson to refrain from serializing `roles` using `@JsonIgnore` if you don't want the property in the result.

Comment: Thanks by the answer, I just want to be sure that when I execute the method } `findUserByLdapId()` it will not fetch the roles list. In the future It may be related with others entities so I don't want to have extra process that may make things slower even if I find a way to avoid showing them in a json response

Answer (score 0):

First of all Hibernate and Spring Data are totally different tools designed for different purposes and they work with each other just fine. You can read more about the differences between both here: [What Is the Difference Between Hibernate and Spring Data JPA?](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-sprin-1)

Spring Data has nothing to do with how you fetch entity's related collections, Hibernate, as an implementation of JPA, does.

I assume you indeed fetch your collection lazily and that happens during serialization of your entity so the mechanism works as it should.

I suggest you to create some sort of DTO object that you could return from your controller rather than returning an entity. It seems like you don't want to expose user's roles so creating a DTO without roles may be a good idea. Other solution is to instruct Jackson to ommit `roles` property during serialization using `@JsonIgnore` annotation.

Comment: As I said in other comment mostly I don't want it to do extra processing, the display here it's not what I care the most,

Comment: Then your code looks fine and you indeed fetch `roles` collection when it's needed.

Comment: So let me ask you something else that I'm surely missing, if I debug this and inspect the User object returned in the controller, I can see the set of roles, why it's that?

Comment: I assume it's because those are fetched under the hood by Jackson during serialization. Jackson "asks" for roles so Hibernate fetches them on demand. If you want to be sure try debugging and look at SQL statements generated by Hibernate.

Comment: I deleted every trace of jackson in my code but I still getting the same result

Comment: What exactly did you delete? Spring uses Jackson internally for serializing and deserializing data in JSON format. If by "deleted every trace of jackson" you mean deleting annotations like `@JsonRootName` then I can assure you that Jackson is doing its job regardless.